# One bottom menu for all activities in app

Tags: android

I'm looking for your help!

I want to create an app with bottom navigation bar. Of coarse it is possible to add menu bar to every activity in app but i want to find solution where i can make one activity with menu and extend it in other activity.

So i made **MenuActivity :**

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
               // mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
               // mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
               // mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationBar);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}}
```

And after that i create some other activity :

```
public class testActivity extends MenuActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
}}
```

And here is the problem, when i start my testActivity its create MenuActivity when calling **super.onCreate()** which contains **setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);**

But i want to add only bottom menu to other activity.  Can you provide me to answer how can i do this?

Thank you all in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved easily with a single Activity and multiple Fragments.
Make an activity which contains only the bottom navigation and a FrameLayout container.
Implement your pages with Fragments and after that, you can load the required fragment in the activity's container with fragment manager

Comment: I already did like that in previous version. But after that i decided that that is a bad practice to make everything in one activity.  In my logic separated app features should be in separated activities. That's why a had asked about it here.

Comment: You were right. I made as i wanted firstly and saw that it would not work in right way.  Thank you!

Comment: Fragment has twice performance than Activity

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) it will help you get desired results.

Comment: Do you mean that i should make everything in one activity and change app context above menu when different menu item will be selected or should i add menu as fragment to all activities ?